# Connection to database not closing

Tags: redis, rust

I'm using "redis-rs" for rust and I tested sending a few thousand requests locally
and it works really well at the few first, except that at some point it stops accepting requests
and starts showing me this error when I send a command to redis:

"Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted"

I am opening a client and a connection on every request to the http server that takes them in,
that's probably a bad idea in the first place, but shouldn't the connections stop existing and close after the function that opened it ends?

Is there any better solution, like some kind of global connection?

thanks

Comment: Hi @getpo.st. It may be helpful if you can provide [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The answer may depend on the way you're using the connections, sync/async environment, your http framework.

Answer (score 0):

Well if it is an http server, the crate you are using likely is doing multithreading to handle requests. It is possible that one thread got caught in the process of closing the connection just as another thread began processing the next request.

Or in your case, maybe the remote database has not finished closing the previous request by the time the next connection is created. Either way, it's easier to think of it as a race condition between threads.

Since you don't know what thread will request a connection next, it may be better to store the connection as a global resource. Since I assume a mutex lock is faster than opening and closing a socket, I used `lazy_static` to create a single thread safe connection.

```rust
use lazy_static::lazy_static;
use parking_lot::Mutex;
use std::sync::Arc;

lazy_static! {
    pub static ref LOCAL_DB: Arc<Mutex<Connection>> = {
        let connection = Connection::open("local.sqlite").expect("Unable to open local DB");
        connection.execute_batch(CREATE_TABLE).unwrap();
        Arc::new(Mutex::new(connection))
    };
}

// I can then just use it anywhere in functions without any complications.
let lock = LOCAL_DB.lock();
lock.execute_batch("begin").unwrap();
// etc.
```

Comment: Oh, that seems like it'll be helpful what about the .lock though, does it mean if another request happens and it's locked, it'll just get an error?

Comment: I prefer to use the `parking_lot` crate since it performs slightly better compared to the standard library `std::sync`. It provides different functions depending on how you want to handle failing to lock. `.lock()` will simply block the current thread until the lock becomes available and won't result in an error. If you don't want to block the thread, you can also use `.try_lock()` instead. It returns `None` if it was unable to obtain the mutex lock at the time of the call. https://docs.rs/parking_lot/0.11.0/parking_lot/type.Mutex.html

Comment: I see, thanks for the detailed reply, going to try it out

Comment: Tried to implement it, but I seem to have some trouble with the fact that the Arc Mutex holds an Option inside of it